# Can't mark seam for my UV

Tags: modeling, animation, uv, rigging

I have a problem with this UV. Can anyone help me? I cannot truly mark seam

[image]

Comment: You have to marks seams on the edges of a mesh itself in _Edit Mode_, not on edges of the UV map in the _UV Editor_. Or at least that's how I interpret what you try to do since I only see a screenshot of the UV map.

Comment: Can I communicate with you via email?

Comment: This site is intended to provide answers for future users who might struggle with the same problem, so communication via email would be of no benefit for this site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.